# Should I post a follow up question, or just add more info to an earlier question that did not have a MWE

Tags: discussion, guidelines

I posted a question related to [PGFplot Axis Labels Detaching From Graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18658/pgfplot-axis-labels-detaching-from-graph) while ago and finally have one small example can reproduce a similar problem.  Is it better for me to post a follow up question (with a cross reference) or just add the example to that posting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the MWE illustrates the existing question, which is how it sounds, post it as a postscript to that.  If the problem raises a related but distinct question, ask a new question.

Comment: That's what I was leaning towards, but didn't know if that question would show up as having been updated anywhere.

Comment: @Peter: If you edit a question, it gets "bumped", which means that it jumps to the top of the front page and becomes first in the ordering of questions by recent activity.  The bumping events are explained on meta.so: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped